# Adding new line characters after a specific amount of bytes

Tags: neovim, replace, binary-file

I'd like to add new line characters after every specific number of bytes in binary mode.

I tried this script but the repetition count depends on the number of characters not bytes. Like when there is 100 characters coded with 102 bytes, the new line will be added after the 100th character. I want to make it depends on bytes.

```
s/.\{100}/&\r/g
```

Is there any way to do that? I'm using neovim.

Comment: You could filter it through Sed on the C locale `:%!LC_ALL=C sed 's/.\{100\}/&\n/g'`.

Comment: It works. Thanks!